# SceneKit crash in unknown (internal?) method

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to integrate some third-party SceneKit code into my app, and I'm experiencing a mysterious crash.  Oddly, the crash gives no error or log in Xcode, and the stack trace is just "UIApplicationMain".  No helpful info there.

The code works in the third-party app where I got it and I've copied it wholesale, so I know it must be some delegate call or some framework that I haven't included, etc.  But this is my first experience with SceneKit so I'm having trouble closing in on what it could be.

The crash happens during an event where the user taps on the screen and a new 3D object is added to the scene.  I've breakpointed all the associated methods, and the crash seems to be happening in the in-between time, presumably the internal SceneKit functionality, so I can't pinpoint it.

My Crashlytics report, though, did pick up some info, which I have included here:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00981ea8 _objc_empty_cache
1  SceneKit                       0x015e0273 __28-[SCNPhysicsBody _setOwner:]_block_invoke + 214
2  SceneKit                       0x016b05b5 C3DTransactionFlush + 2014
3  CoreFoundation                 0x00bff86e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00bff7b0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
5  CoreFoundation                 0x00bf51ea __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
6  CoreFoundation                 0x00bf4a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
7  CoreFoundation                 0x00bf488b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
8  GraphicsServices               0x043042c9 GSEventRunModal + 192
9  GraphicsServices               0x04304106 GSEventRun + 104
10 UIKit                          0x01b99106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
11 SW LiveSheet                   0x0007888a main (main.m:14)
12 libdyld.dylib                  0x04e61ac9 start + 1
```

A search of my project finds no examples of `SCNPhysicsBody _setOwner:`, so I'm assuming that is an internal SceneKit method?

Does anyone know what might be causing a crash like this?  I'll include any methods that might be relevant (if you tell me what they might be), but the series of methods to create the object is very long, so it didn't seem productive to blindly copy it all here.  Plus, as I said, the crash seems to be happening "between the methods" anyway.

Does anyone recognize this error?  Or are there any common "getting started with SceneKit" mistakes that I might be making, that could lead to this?  I know the code works because it works in the other project, it's just a matter of what got lost in translation.  Also, the scene does load successfully before the tap begins the process of adding the new object.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Even just an idea of where to investigate would be appreciated.

Thanks for helping out a SceneKit newbie!

Comment: You are probably missing a few variables or objects initialization. Could you post the function where the error happens, any initialization and variable storing?

Comment: @Moustach That's the problem: I've breakpointed the beginning and end of every single method, and the crash seems to happen after the end of either `-(void)handleTap:` or `- (void)renderer:updateAtTime:`, but before another method fires.  I take that to mean that it's crashing in the internal functionality of SceneKit?  But I don't know how to dig into a method that doesn't exist in my code, and the full DiceRollerView class is 1128 lines long, so just posting the whole thing wouldn't be terribly helpful.

Comment: Hm... How about posting the code that create the cube (I assume), and its physics body? Sadly without code there is only so much we can do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weirdly, the answer ended up being just running the app on a device.  I never could figure out what was wrong in the Simulator, but as soon as I tried running it on a device, it worked without changing anything!

Frustrating, to try to hunt down a solution for such a weird thing, but hopefully this will help anyone who experiences something similar.

**If you're doing something with SceneKit and you're getting a bizarre error like this, try running it on a device before you tear too much of your hair out.**